# Apache HTTP server is not running

Tags: apache, ubuntu, ssl, apache2

I have build a website on Ubuntu 18.04 and tried to install SSL (Let's Encrypt) for the domain. So I installed everything from the guides, but after it I could not access admin panel for my website, as well as cannot upload or download any files from FTP server.

So I decided to delete everything related to SSL (from some guides on internet) and I was thinking that somehow it will come back to previous situation. However, it did not happened.

Now I cannot upload anything to the FTP or download from it. Cannot access the admin page as well. I have a access to server root, so this is the only way (as I understand) to fix the problem.

I have tried to do this:

```
sudo certbot --apache -d domain.lt -d www.domain.lt
```

However I get the error:

```
    Error while running apache2ctl configtest.
Action configtest failed. The Apache error log may have more information.apache2:
Syntax error on line 225 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 13 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/opencart-le-ssl.conf: Could not open configuration file /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf: No such file or directory
```

I see that Apache is not running and do not know how to make it run.

```
● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2020-10-16 13:16:42 EEST; 11min ago
  Process: 18181 ExecStop=/usr/sbin/apachectl stop (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 18186 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 366 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS) 
Oct 16 13:16:42 domain.lt systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Oct 16 13:16:42 domain.lt apachectl[18186]: apache2: Syntax error on line 225 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 13 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/opencart-le-ssl.conf:
Oct 16 13:16:42 domain.lt apachectl[18186]: Action 'start' failed.
```

Any help how to enable ssl and make it work again is appreciated. I am not very good as sysadmin, just following the guides.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to enter the website however still cannot log in into /admin panel. I am entering username and password, however nothing happens.
FTP still remains only for navigation, cannot upload or download files.